# Pluralization does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

*Rails 4.0.2*

I can't make work pluralization properly. Only `:zero`, `:one` and `:other` works. But I need all of forms: `:zero`, `:one`, `:few`, `:many`, `:other`.

In the `config/initializers` folder file `pluralization.rb` has been created:

Variant 1:

```
require "i18n/backend/pluralization"
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)
{
:ru => { :i18n => { :plural => { :keys => [:one, :few, :many, :other], :rule => lambda { |n| n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ? :one : [2, 3, 4].include?(n % 10) && ![12, 13, 14].include?(n % 100) ? :few : n % 10 == 0 || [5, 6, 7, 8, 9].include?(n % 10) || [11, 12, 13, 14].include?(n % 100) ? :many : :other } } } }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
require "i18n/backend/pluralization"
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)
```

In the `config/locales` file `ru.yml` has been created:

```
ru:
  kids:
    zero: ru_zero
    one: ru_one
    few: ru_few
    many: ru_many
    other: ru_other
```

In application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
```

Test code:

```
0.upto 15 {|i|
  i.to_s + " "
  t(:kids, count: i)
}
```

Output:

```
0 ru_zero
1 ru_one
2 ru_other
3 ru_other
4 ru_other
5 ru_other
6 ru_other
7 ru_other
8 ru_other
9 ru_other
10 ru_other
11 ru_other
12 ru_other
13 ru_other
14 ru_other
15 ru_other
```

I confused.